# how use Crypt32.dll in C# to be compatible in mono

Tags: c#, linux, dll, mono, certificate

i'm trying to use native function of Crypt32.dll in C# program and after that i will use mono to run my app in linux. is there any suggestion to do this ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since Linux does not have a Crypto32.dll, you cannot call it natively. You could try the [System.Security.Cryptography](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=N%3aSystem.Security.Cryptography) or the [Mono.Security.Cryptography](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=N%3aMono.Security.Cryptography) namespace.

Comment: functions of System.Security.Cryptography  are the same with Crypt32.dll ?